# flash action script of an object triggered from another non-flash object on the same web page

Tags: flash, actionscript, triggers, navigationbar

How would you trigger an action script in a flash object by another object that is not a flash object?  For example, I have flash based navigation bar; as I hover over each nav button a message displayed in a display window stating the purpose of the button hovered over. That message is only for information.  Nothing happens unless I click the button.

Now I would like to have the same message display effect in the same flash message area when I hover over another object on the web page, say another image or button.  These however are not part of flash navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface on your SWF using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) callbacks. That way, any script on the container - e.g. a JavaScript function on an HTML page - can call your SWF and pass it parameters or call a method to display your message.

If it's Flash to Flash (e.g. one SWF communicating with a different SWF) you can also go the ExternalInterface route (SWF->JS->SWF), but it's probably simpler to just use a [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) instead. It also allows SWF in different pages to talk to each other.